# Calculating distance between two shape files given a connecting poly line

Tags: geospatial, distance, arcgis

I am having some difficulty in determining the best strategy on approaching calculating distance from drainage considering wildfires. Here is a
[screenshot of the data (wildfires, flow line, and nearest lake)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyP01.jpg). Ultimately, I am interested in calculating the distance according to the NHD flow line from the wildfire to the lake.  Granted, I have multiple lakes (~80), so I would also like to limit the distance of a buffer of about 100 miles.

There are multiple inlets for every lake, so all the tributaries that connect is wanted along with the shortest distance (where the function/method would choose the shortest tributary connecting the fire and lake).

I am posting this in two sections since I am open to two strategies of handling this. I believe this can be done in ArcGIS Pro. I have looked into the least-cost path approach, which could be valid for the shortest distance where the source is the wildfire and the lake as source path, but not sure which cost path approach is more suitable given my dataset (shapefiles/lines).

I appreciate the patience and suggestions. I am more than open to rephrasing my question in order for it to make more sense. I was not sure where to go from here which is why I decided to post.

Wildfire data is from MTBS (link here https://www.mtbs.gov/direct-download (any individual fire, an example is ID: CA3474011878120020618, wildfire name is CAPCO
Lakes are from NASA CYAN website: https://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/projects/cyan/ at the bottom titled *Lake Shapefile for MERIS and OLCI sensors*
NHD Flow lines from: https://www.usgs.gov/national-hydrography/access-national-hydrography-products

Comment: Is the picture a visual representation of your data, or the actual data?  In other words, do you have actual numbers to calculate with?

Comment: It is a screenshot from ArcGIS. I can add example data if it would help.